# Finding a function that satisfies a condition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find a function $f(x)$ defined on an interval $(a, b)$ such that $$\lim_{h\to0} |f (x + h)- f(x-
h)| = 0$$ 
while $$\lim_{h\to0} |f (x + h)- f(x)| = 0$$ 
does not equal to $0$ for some $x$.

Comment: Please write a question more clear. You wrote down explicitly both limes equal to 0. Then you say that something $=0$ should not be equal to zero… Please formulate cleanly!

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is $$\lim_{h\to0} |f (x + h)- f(x-h)| = 0$$ while $$\lim_{h\to0} |f (x + h)- f(x)| \neq 0$$

Take:
$$f(0)=1, f(x)=0 \ x \neq 0$$